I am trying to get list of databases from AWS Glue using AWS Glue SDK for Java 1.X with limited resource access on policy but getting empty list
As mentioned in title, I am trying to fetch list of databases from AWS Glue.
I have plenty of databases listed in Glue. I am using a policy with limited resource access so that I can only see specific type of databases.
These are my policies with respective permission:
1.resource-policy
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "glue:GetConnections",
                "glue:GetTables",
                "glue:GetTableVersions",
                "glue:GetDatabases",
                "glue:GetTable",
                "glue:GetDatabase",
                "glue:GetJob",
                "glue:StartJobRun",
                "glue:BatchStopJobRun",
                "glue:GetCrawler"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:glue:*:248135293344:connection/*",
                "arn:aws:glue:*:248135293344:job/*",
                "arn:aws:glue:*:248135293344:database/glue*",
                "arn:aws:glue:*:248135293344:catalog",
                "arn:aws:glue:*:248135293344:table/glue*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}


S3 policy

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

When I do a query through AWS CLI using the following command:
aws glue get-databases --query "DatabaseList[*].Name"

I get the following output:

But when I try to do the query using AWS SDK for Java I get no results. These are my code snippets and results:
package alation.awsglue.mde.extractor;

import alation.aws.auth.AWSAuthentication;
import alation.awsglue.Main;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.AWSGlue;
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.AWSGlueClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.model.AWSGlueException;
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.model.Database;
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.model.GetDatabasesRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.model.GetDatabasesResult;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

import java.util.List;

public class sampleMDE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("com.amazonaws.sdk.enableDefaultMetrics", "true");
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("log4j.properties"));
        AWSGlue amazonGlueClient = null;
        try{
        // Initialize the Glue client
        AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredProvider =
            new AWSAuthentication(
                "<your_key>",
                "<your_id>")
                .getCredential();
        amazonGlueClient = AWSGlueClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(awsCredProvider)
            .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Failed to create Glue client: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
        try{

        // Create the request
        GetDatabasesRequest request = new GetDatabasesRequest();

        // Get the list of databases
        GetDatabasesResult response = amazonGlueClient.getDatabases(request);

        // Process the response
        List<Database> databases = response.getDatabaseList();
        if (databases.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No databases found.");
        }
        for (Database database : databases) {
            System.out.println("Database name: " + database.getName());
        }
    } catch (AWSGlueException e) {
        System.err.println("Error occurred while retrieving databases: " + e.getErrorMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}




I had a talk with AWS support team and got to know that at times the initial pages can be empty while fetching the databases. So need to opt for pagination in such and in general all conditions. Following code snippet worked for me:

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.AWSGlue;
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.AWSGlueClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.model.AWSGlueException;
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.model.Database;
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.model.GetDatabasesRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.model.GetDatabasesResult;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class sampleMDE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("com.amazonaws.sdk.enableDefaultMetrics", "true");
        AWSGlue amazonGlueClient = null;
        try{
        // Initialize the Glue client
        AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredProvider =
            new AWSAuthentication(
                "<ID>",
                "<SECRET>")
                .getCredential();
        amazonGlueClient = AWSGlueClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(awsCredProvider)
            .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to create Glue client: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        try{
            // Process the response
            String nextToken = null;
            List<Database> databases = new ArrayList<>();
            do {
                GetDatabasesRequest request = new GetDatabasesRequest()
                    .withNextToken(nextToken);

                GetDatabasesResult result = amazonGlueClient.getDatabases(request);
                databases.addAll(result.getDatabaseList());

                nextToken = result.getNextToken();
            } while (nextToken != null);
            if (databases.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("No databases found.");
            }
            for (Database database : databases) {
                System.out.println("Database name: " + database.getName());
            }
        } catch (AWSGlueException e) {
            System.err.println("Error occurred while retrieving databases: " + e.getErrorMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}



I'd check few things:

If the AWS credentials in the Java program are the same as the one used to test the command with AWS CLI.
If the Glue databases are in US-EAST-1 or other regions.


Thanks @megahf for raising these 2 cautious checks. I have thoroughly checked these and they both are same for CLI and API based calls. I am sure anyone who reproduces this error will also face the same issue.
